# Is there a way to find out which Bluetooth device is plugged into which USB port?

Tags: usb, bluetooth, bluez

I'm using two Bluetooth adaptors with BlueZ, both are the same device but with different types of antenna, is there any method to find out which usb port the identifier on BlueZ (hci0/hci1) is referring to?

I can discover the MAC address of the device through hcitool dev, so if there was a way to discover which USB port the adaptor with that MAC address was connected to, that would also solve my problem.

As both the adaptors are the same model, lsusb does not provide any identifying information I can use.

Using Ubuntu 16.04. I am looking for a solution in any form, whether it is a shell command or java/C/python/etc.

Comment: What environment are you asking this question about? Shell? Programming language?

Comment: Clarified in a edit, I am looking for a solution in any form, whether it is a shell command or java/C/python/etc. Thanks

Comment: Unplug one of them, `hcitool dev`